# Full Text Search in email content with list of keywords in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am writing an application where I want to scan email content (body/subject) with set of keywords (on high traffic email server).

My keywords list is around 400K (and changing on daily level), I am using SOLR and indexing my keywords as indexes (keywords also contain various fields like firstname, lastname, goods etc).

Now question is, how email body which is free text data can be searched with keywords via SOLR query.

As an example, my keyword is "XYZ Wines" and if email body shows "Hi This is XYZ and I am sending you some Wines" or "Hi sending you some XYZ Wines, thanks for your business" in both case I should get search HIT with different search scores.

Answer (score 2):

Index your emails, then search for `+XYZ +Wines` (or better yet set `q.op=AND`) and use [pf/ps](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29) to boost term proximity.

Comment: technically I may not able to index emails due to volume.....if I index email I may need to query each keywords (100s of thousands) in email content....

Comment: @Rushik: I'm not sure what you mean... obviously Solr/Lucene can only search within an index. Also it's very easy to index emails with Solr, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MailEntityProcessor

Comment: Sure Mauricio, I totally understand but I dont want to query each keywords (thousands) to my indexed emails to get HIT, rather I might pre-process email body (remove common terms etc) and each term in email search with indexed keywords.

Comment: @Rushik : sorry, I really don't understand. It seems you somehow want to get hits without actually running any queries? Doesn't make much sense, so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my initial idea was to index keywords (XYZ Wines etc) and query will be "email content" thus from query if any of the word(s) is part of indexed keyword consider as HIT. As per your suggestion if I index emails than I need to consider all keywords as my query (one by one)

Comment: @Rushik IMHO you're doing it the other way around, the text is the email, the query is the keyword. That's what Solr/Lucene are designed to do.

Comment: Well, tht's the way you suggested and I am sure thats possible, but my expectation was to index keywords (100s of thousands) and query email content to see if any of the keyword found in email - something like "if email_body.contains(any of keyword) consider as HIT".......I need to see if I need to use some other technology.......thanks for your help...

Comment: @Rushik : it may be possible to do what you want but it's probably not going to be trivial or not yield good results... as it basically subverts the normal usage of Solr.